# comparison function must return int, not long

Tags: python, sorting

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,n,x):
        self.n = n
        self.x = x

a = C('a',1)
b = C('b',2)
c = C('c',3)

classList = [b,a,c]

for q in classList: print q.n,

classList.sort(lambda a,b: long(a.x - b.x))

for q in classList: print q.n,
```

Running the code above would get the error `TypeError: comparison function must return int, not long`.
Is there another clean way to sort class objects by certain class variables?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the built-in `cmp` function: `cmp(a.x, b.x)`

By the way, you can also utilize the `key` parameter of `sort`:

`classList.sort(key=lambda c: c.x)`

which is faster.

According to [wiki.python.org](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/):

> This technique is fast because the key function is called exactly once
>   for each input record.

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you need `long`

```
class C:
    def __init__(self,n,x):
        self.n = n
        self.x = x

a = C('a',1)
b = C('b',2)
c = C('c',3)

classList = [b,a,c]

for q in classList: print q.n,

classList.sort(lambda a,b: a.x - b.x)

for q in classList: print q.n,
```

Output:

```
b a c a b c
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `cmp` function, use a `key` function - it is more efficient, and doesn't have this kind of restriction on what types it can return:

```
classList.sort(key=lambda a: a.x)
```

This is also more future proof: `cmp` functions are no longer supported in Python 3, and continue to exist in Python 2 in order to support old code (from before `key` existed).

Answer (score 0):

You can just add the comparison you want to your class:

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self,n,x):
        self.n = n
        self.x = x

    def __cmp__(self,other):
        return cmp(self.x,other.x)
```